# Why following code doesn't produce any output?

Tags: c++, g++4.8

Why the code below doesn't produce any output? I expected it to be `42 s`. How to fix it?

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdarg>

void foo(const char* format, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    printf(format, args);
    va_end(args);
}

int main()
{
    foo("%d %s\n", 42, "s");
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/EsHsRO

Actually, it produces http://codepad.org/k7ld231E.
Why the `foo` is wrong?

Comment: Why not just use `printf()`?

Comment: @herohuyongtao it is just an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`vprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/vfprintf) instead: **`int vprintf( const char* format, va_list vlist );`**

```
vprintf(format, args);
```

`printf()` and friends are for normal use. `vprintf()` and friends are for when you want to write your own `printf()`-like functions.